# Major Memory Leak in Android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

In my attempts to optimize my Pathfinding, I have run into some pretty serious memory leaks.  Here are just a few of the messages that go constantly.

```
07-03 15:26:14.179  23501-23503/com.totalannihilationroadrage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4104K, 29% free 14506K/20195K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-03 15:26:14.689  23501-23503/com.totalannihilationroadrage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4062K, 29% free 14506K/20195K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-03 15:26:15.199  23501-23503/com.totalannihilationroadrage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4032K, 29% free 14537K/20195K, paused 1ms+3ms
07-03 15:26:15.709  23501-23503/com.totalannihilationroadrage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4103K, 29% free 14506K/20195K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-03 15:26:16.209  23501-23503/com.totalannihilationroadrage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4062K, 29% free 14506K/20195K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-03 15:26:16.729  23501-23503/com.totalannihilationroadrage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4020K, 28% free 14549K/20195K, paused 2ms+2ms
07-03 15:26:17.229  23501-23503/com.totalannihilationroadrage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4118K, 29% free 14506K/20195K, paused 2ms+3ms
07-03 15:26:17.739  23501-23503/com.totalannihilationroadrage D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 4062K, 29% free 14506K/20195K, paused 1ms+4ms
```

Since there was no leak previously, I can only assume it's in the only function where I made changes, which would be here:

```
public void addChild(int row, int col, TiledMap tiles, Node currentNode, Node goal, Direction facing)
{
    Node child;
    Node tempChildNode = new Node(row, col, currentNode.gCost, currentNode.fCost, currentNode, facing);
    if((row >= 0 && col >= 0) && (row <= tiles.height && col <= tiles.width))
    {
        if (tiles.isPassable(row, col))
        {
            if (!isClosed(tempChildNode, closedList))
            {
                double g = currentNode.gCost + getDistanceFromParent(tempChildNode, currentNode);
                double f = g + getDistance(row, col, currentNode);

                if(isOpen(tempChildNode, openList))
                {
                    child = new Node(row, col, currentNode.gCost, currentNode.fCost, currentNode, facing);

                    if(child.gCost > g)
                    {
                        child.fCost = f;
                        child.gCost = g;
                        child.parentNode = currentNode;
                    }
                }
                if(!isOpen(tempChildNode, openList))
                {
                    child = new Node(row, col, g, f, currentNode, facing);
                    openList.add(child);

                    if(child.gCost > g)
                    {
                        child.fCost = f;
                        child.gCost = g;
                        child.parentNode = currentNode;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The section that was modified was:

```
if(isOpen(tempChildNode, openList))
{
    child = new Node(row, col, currentNode.gCost, currentNode.fCost, currentNode, facing);

    if(child.gCost > g)
    {
        child.fCost = f;
        child.gCost = g;
        child.parentNode = currentNode;
    }
}
if(!isOpen(tempChildNode, openList))
{
    child = new Node(row, col, g, f, currentNode, facing);
    openList.add(child);

    if(child.gCost > g)
    {
        child.fCost = f;
        child.gCost = g;
        child.parentNode = currentNode;
    }
}
```

Which changed from:

```
Node child = getChildFromOpen(row, col);

if (child == null)
{
    child = new Node(row, col, g, f, currentNode, facing);
    openList.add(child);
}
else if(child.gCost > g)
{
    child.fCost = f;
    child.gCost = g;
    child.parentNode = currentNode;
}
```

`getChildFromOpen()` was a function that looped through the `openList` and returned a `Node` if it was found, and `null` if it was not. This function was replaced with `isOpen` which returns a `boolean`, `true` if it was found `false` if it wasn't.

Comment: When seeing these messages myself, I typically associated it with just resources being garbage collected, not a memory leak in your application.  Is there something that would lead you to believe it is a memory leak?

Comment: I figured it was as the game never ends up completing the function that it's running through. That or it takes longer than the 30 minutes I was willing to wait.

Comment: I don't think you have a memory leak! As Jay said, it's only the GC. If you would have a  memory  leak the "20195K" would go up at another value!

Comment: Any idea what this might be? This is my first experience developing for Android, and so far it has not stop running with nothing happening except logcat spamming `GC_CONCURRENT`

Comment: Dump a HPROF file from DDMS and see what's happening there.